# Error: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-loc

[image]

This code isn't working in Jupyter IDE. I can't find my mistake. Please help.

The first 5 rows of the dataframe I am using is shown here:
[image]

Comment: Please share the code and output as text, not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
df.loc[df['compound'] > 0,'SentimentType'] = 'Positive'
df.loc[df['compound'] < 0,'SentimentType'] = 'Negative'
df.loc[df['compound'] == 0,'SentimentType'] = 'Neutral'
```

Instead of retrieving the column through `df.compound,` you should do `df['compound']`. You can also tell from the error message that you received that `df.compound` is a method name and not the column that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compare values of 'compound' column, you must use df['compound'] instead of df.compound, which is a method.

Maybe the following code can help you:

Function to classify 'Sentiment_Type'

```
def sentiment(score):
    if score < 0:
        return "Negative"
    elif score > 0:
        return "Positive"
    else:
        return "Neutral"
```

After, you can use this function to create a new column

```
df['Sentiment_Type'] = df['compound'].apply(sentiment)
```

Answer (score 0):

add brackets to 1 st line df.compund() >0

Comment: Please check the question once again. I have added the first five rows of the data frame I am using.